# How to change background by changing theme?

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have a background image as cover setted in my  by css class, now i would like to remove it and apply background color..

I've tried making a function to change theme, for example from light to dark and it's work, but i don't know how to unset background theme and use background color..

I need to use ngif ?

my background is here:

```
<router-outlet class="cover-background">
```

this on my app.ts

```
     constructor(public overlayContainer: OverlayContainer){}

      @HostBinding('class') componentCssClass;

      onSetTheme(theme) {
        this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(theme);
        this.componentCssClass = theme;
      }
```

this in my theme.scss

```
    .dark-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($dark);
}

    .light-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($theme);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ngClass directive.